# What is the brand of this threaded insert

Tags: cabinets, hinges

[image]

This is the reverse of a Blum hinge that is no longer made. The threaded insert is broken. The screw is M5.  The 6 refers to the length of the threaded insert.
Do you recognise the logo of the threaded insert to find a replacement?
The thread goes all the way through to the other side.

[image]

Comment: Make a bit to go in or consider new hinges.

Comment: You might consider a thread repair kit like helicoil, their are other brands , this or a fire drill with a wire welder could fill the hole and retap it, I mention wire welder because that piece won’t take much heat. I have used both methods to repair damaged threads in the past.

Comment: I’ve used epoxy in stripped threads with great success. As long as you never want to disassemble it, this might be an option.